# verifying cuda 7.5 installation on Ubuntu

Tags: cuda

I've installed cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 via

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Looks fine judging by `nvcc -V` output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

but I have no `/usr/local/cuda` directory, which as I gather should exist as well as contain samples that can be used for verifying the installation (maybe my expectation to have this directory is incorrect).

What might be wrong, or how should I otherwise verify the installation?

Comment: What is your goal having installed cuda?  My recommendation is to try to accomplish those goals to 'verify the installation'.  Could you also edit your question to provide the guide or information that gives you the idea about `/usr/local/cuda`?

Comment: I think you have to install `cuda-samples` as well. Might be that you have to prepend the cuda version. But that should provide the cuda samples to quickly test your setup.

Comment: `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` must be an oddball here, as apparently [7.5 isn't officially supported for 16.04](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-75-downloads-archive). I'll try installing version 8 instead. Thanks anyway, and I _hope_ it will work with my target version of torch..